# What hash algorithm is it?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, hash

I've found a simple multiply-with-add hash function in an old Usenet post.
Can someone identify what hash algorithm is it? An algorithm name or any attribution?

```
size_t hash(const char* data, size_t length, size_t seed = 1)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        seed = seed * (UCHAR_MAX + 2U) + data[i];
    }

    return seed;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hash function is very similar to a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), a type of naive pseudorandom number generator. By now there are much better hash functions out there, and I suggest not using this one.